# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate' even though its installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip

I am in a Jupyter Notebook and ran inside a cell

```
!pip3 install tabulate
```

It returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.8.10)
```

Also when I run

```
!pip3 freeze
```

I am seeing `tabulate==0.8.10`.

However, when I now try to import `tabulate` via

```
from tabulate import tabulate
```

It throws

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

Even when I restart the kernel it doesn't work.

Can anyone help why it can't import it?

Comment: check if your  Jupyter Notebook interpreter is set correctly to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9` 
most likely your interpreter is using some other version of python in which tabulate is not installed

Comment: Also, any advice using an exclamation point with `pip install` inside a notebook is outdated. Please use the modern magic command added to insure the package is installed in the environment backing the notebook, something the use of the exclamation point alone doesn't do. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic command `%pip install` meant to be run inside cells in notebooks, and also the related `%conda install` command.

Comment: @Wayne Awesome, using the `%` solved it. Thanks so much to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
%pip install <module-name>
```

instead of `!pip install <module-name>` in a jupyter notebook cell solved the issue.

This answer came from @Wayne.